# onclick property of button is executed when button is created with "createElement"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button on my webpage that executes the function "AddBox()".  This function creates a div called "box" and in that div other elements are created, like (another) div, a label, an input and a button.
Everytime a "box" is created, it gets a unique id which is "box1", "box2", "box3",...

Now I need a way to delete a certain box. Within every box I also create a button that should serve as a way to remove the box.  The button is called "buttonRemove".  The function to remove the box is called "removeBox()".

I tried to give the button upon creation "removeBox()" as a onclink property.  This function however also got executed when created.

How can I give the "removeBox()" function to the button "removeBox" so that I can add several "boxes" and remove the box in which I clicked on button "Remove".

```js
var count = 0;

function addBox() {

  count++

  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.id = "box" + count;

  var stepTitle = document.createElement("h2")
  stepTitle.innerText = "Title " + count;

  var divName = document.createElement("div");
  divName.className = "fields";
  var labelName = document.createElement("label");
  labelName.htmlfor = "Name";
  labelName.innerHTML = "Name";
  var inputName = document.createElement("input");
  inputName.type = "text";
  inputName.name = "Name";
  inputName.id = "Name";

  var buttonRemove = document.createElement("button");
  buttonRemove.innerText = "Remove box" + count +" with Title "+count;
  buttonRemove.type = "button";
  
 
  divName.appendChild(labelName);
  divName.appendChild(inputName);

  box.appendChild(stepTitle);
  box.appendChild(divName);
  box.appendChild(buttonRemove)

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(box);
}

function removeBox(){
       document.getElementById().remove(); 
}
```

```css
.fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

label {
  flex-basis: 10rem;
}

input{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="addBox()">Add box</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do this: `function removeBox(num) { document.getElementById('box'+num).remove() }`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give the button a `click` event handler that locates the ancestor `div` it is located in and removes it.

**Notes:**

Stay away from giving elements `id`s. They seem easy enough at first, but they make the code harder to scale and become difficult to maintain as the code gets more complex. In the working code below, note that I've removed the `id` from the elements and changed the `label` so that the `input` is a child of it, which removes the need for the `for` attribute (which relies on an `id`). Overall, the code is simpler.

Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` as `.textContent` is a W3C standard and `.innerText` (while ubiquitous and supported everywhere, is a WHATWG, but not W3C standard).

```js
var count = 0;

function addBox() {

  count++

  var box = document.createElement("div");

  var stepTitle = document.createElement("h2")
  stepTitle.textContent = "Title " + count;

  var divName = document.createElement("div");
  divName.className = "fields";
  
  var labelName = document.createElement("label");
  labelName.textContent = "Name";
  
  var inputName = document.createElement("input");
  inputName.type = "text";
  inputName.name = "Name";
  
  // By nesting a form field within a label, they automatically
  // become associated without the need for the "for" attribute
  // and therefore any id.
  labelName.appendChild(inputName);

  var buttonRemove = document.createElement("button");
  buttonRemove.textContent = "Remove box" + count +" with Title "+count;
  buttonRemove.type = "button";
  
  // Give the remove button a click event handler
  buttonRemove.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    // Find the nearest div ancestor and remove it.
    this.closest("div").remove();
  });
  
 
  divName.appendChild(labelName);

  box.appendChild(stepTitle);
  box.appendChild(divName);
  box.appendChild(buttonRemove)

  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(box);
}

function removeBox(){
       document.getElementById().remove(); 
}
```

```css
.fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

label {
  flex-basis: 10rem;
}

input{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="addBox()">Add box</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```